# Cannot add assemblies to .Net Core application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net-core, assemblies, visual-studio-2019

When I try to add a missing assembly to my project (for unit testing specifically) I noticed that the Assemblies tab is missing in the "Add Reference" dialog , see:

[image]

Is this a bug or a expected behavior? If it's expected how we are supposed to add the missing assemblies.

Note that I already tried through Nuget package manager and still didn't work.

Comment: On Nuget Package Manager did you select `Browse` instead of `Installed` Tab?

Comment: @Stam, Yes, actually I have installed the assemblies (through Nuget) and still is not working.

Comment: Well I had a strange problem a couple of times with VS 2019. I was adding a package via Nuget and then VS was removing those libraries after a while. Restarting VS fixed this problem. Did you check if the lib is under Dependences/Nuget?

Comment: Yes, they are, but they show a warning icon as if they were missing

Comment: Do you have a warning message in the error list of vs?

Comment: The warning icon is in the Reference List, the error list only shows the missing namespace errors

Comment: Did you try to uninstall it and install it again from nuget?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, I even updated to latest version and rolled back to the previous and nothing. Could it be something wrong with VS 2019 or maybe .Net Core (I'm using version 3.0 preview 6 BTW)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is correct behaviour. The Assemblies tab is not available for Net Core projects. You wont be able to add assemblies from your system, because Net Core projects work with dependencies from Nuget. So, to add your references, you need to use the Nuget Package Manager instead.

1. Right click your project
2. Choose "Manage Nuget Packages"
3. Find the package you want to add from the list

Comment: @Robert_Perry the references to my assemblies are already installed in the Nuget references of my project (since I created the project as a Unit Test Core Project they were added automatically) but still got the error of the missing assemblies.

Comment: Have you rebuilt your solution and used the “Restore Nuget Packages” option?

Comment: I think VS 2019 doesn't have the "Restore Nuget Packages" option anymore. Instead it has a "Package Restore" section and I already had everything enabled there.

Comment: This answer is slightly incorrect. Actually you can add assembly references from the file system, see norgie's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You can add external assemblies, e.g. Rebex, by right clicking your project, select Add >> Project Reference... >> Browse and then hit the Browse button.

I've just done that using VS2019 v.16.9.4 on a .Net Core 3.1.x project. No problem at all.

Comment: This works well. Would never have expected to be able to add assembly references under "Add Project Reference ..."